# CPU load strongly increasing when calling update() SLOT on several QQuickWindows

Tags: qt, animation, qml, cpu, qtquick2

I found that my application consumes more and more CPU power in time when making a  calling update() SLOT on several QQuickWindows.

Here is a simple test program:

```
    import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {visible: true; width: 640; height: 480;
    Window{  height: 100;  width: 100; visible: true; objectName: "w1"; id:w1; }
    Window{  height: 100;  width: 100; visible: true; objectName: "w2"; id:w2; }
    Window{  height: 100;  width: 100; visible: true; objectName: "w3"; id:w3; }

    Timer {
        interval: 30
        repeat: true
        running: true

        onTriggered: {
            w1.update();
            w2.update();
            w3.update();
        } 
    }
}
```

If I completely reload QQuickWindows with `Loader`, everything resets and CPU load starts to increase from beginning.

This issue was tested with the following two systems:

- Ubuntu 12.04 + Qt5.4.2 + intel_video + opensource videodriver
- Ubuntu14.04 + Qt5.3.2 + radeon_video + opensource videodriver

*I need a quick fix for this!!!* I had already tried to periodically call `releaseResources()` method and `resetOpenGLState()` method of `QQuickWindow`.

ALso very interesting is that when I apply `putenv("LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1")` in my `main.cpp`, this issue goes away and I have *CONSTANT* low cpu usage. But in my real application I need hardware rendering, so it is *not* an option for me.

Can anyone test this issue or give me an advise?

Comment: Try instantiating both images in separate Image elements and control their visibility with visible: sw

Comment: I am just swapping two images because it is just a test program. In my actual program i were acquiring images from camera. And i spend a day only to understand that this CPU issue is not related with camera, but with image drawing (or maybe even just a window content redrawing). It was very unexpected for me.

Comment: ALso very interesting is that when I apply putenv("LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1"); in main.cpp this issue goes away and i have CONSTANT low cpu usage. But in my real application I need hardware rendering, so it is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code on my `Ubuntu 14.04 + Qt5.4 + amd proprietary drives` without any increase in CPU load (it remained constant). With reloading of image in every 30 milliseconds, gives a frame rate of 33.3 fps. I guess you are using open source drive which are not so good in rendering. Try using amd proprietary drive on our amd machine.

Comment: Yes that worked for me. Simple program runs with constant CPU usage! Thank you! But my main application refused to work with this driver. It complains on absence of swrast_dri.so and gives errors trying to draw shaders. Trying to fix it now.

Comment: @DimaK is it because you have left `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE` on?

Comment: no. It was because my main program tried to use opensource drivers. I edited .pro file and it started to work fine. But my target PCs are with radeon x300 videoadapter, and propryetary driver does not support it anymore. Legacy driver refuses to install on ubuntu 12.04. So I am trying to find other solution. I had already tryed to install fresh(10.5.8) mesa library but issue still stayed... don't know what else to try.